# Proof help - Calculus - infimum of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I need some help proving the following question:

Let $a < b$ and let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be an increasing function.

Prove that there exists an $s\in \mathbb R$ such that $s = \inf \{f (x) ~| ~a < x ≤ b\}$.

So, I would like to say that due to the definition of increasing function, for every $x_{1} < x_{2}$, we get $f(x_{1}) < f(x_{2})$.

From here I am a little confused, because it seems so obvious that there exists an infimum for this set.

Every hint will be so appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you think the infimum of the set is?

Comment: Once you're confident about the infimum, you'll have to prove it rigorously. For that, first prove that it is a lower bound. Next, prove that any other lower bound is smaller than or equal to this lower bound.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! :)

Comment: Note that this method is useful if you can guess or find the infimum before persuing with the proof. In this case, as pointed out by @Guest, the infimum need not be $f(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

The number $f(a)$ is a lower bound of the set $\{f(x)\,|\,a<x\leq b\}$ because $f$ is increasing.

Therefore the set has a real infimum as a consequence of the completeness of the real numbers.

Note that $f$ is not assumed to be continuous, so the infimum is not necessarily $f(a)$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for that! :)

Comment: @Guest Oh wow, I totally missed that. Yeah $f$ need not be continuous. This is the right answer.

Comment: Instead it is appropriate to write the infimum as $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$.

Comment: Interesting. I will try proving that too!